# How map a servername apache in docker container on host client?

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, virtualhost, server-name

I have a docker container with apache and configured my .conf file with a virtual hosts, calling from the client test.dev the virtual host docker is not mapped. If I call localhost it works correctly.

Thanks!!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername test.dev
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/test/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/test/public">
             DirectoryIndex index.php
             AllowOverride All
             Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hostnames can't be "mapped" to a docker container. If you really want to access it locally with a hostname you might want to inject the Host header to every requests or use your hostfile.

**Inject the Host header**

Whenever I want to test something quickly what I usually do is use `curl`. If you bind the container to port 8080 on your host:

```
curl -XGET -H "Host: test.dev" http://localhost:8080
```

**Configure the hostfile**

You will have to add `127.0.0.1 test.dev` to the hostfile. The path is relative to your OS:

- On Windows: `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- On Unix: `/etc/hosts`

Once this is done, you can open the browser and head to `http://test.dev:8080`